# Why isn't the LINQ-to-SQL result I'm updating saving?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm attempting to update a result from a LINQ-to-SQL query like below:

```
foreach (var selectedItem in lvFolders.SelectedItems)
{
        Folder folder = selectedItem as Folder;
        folder.IsNeeded = "N";

        var dbResult = from r in _dataContext.AllDFSDatas
                       where ((r.FolderPath == folder.FolderPath) && (r.COO == cboCOO.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                       select r;

        foreach (var result in dbResult)
        {
            result.StillNeeded = "N";
        }

        try
        {
            var test = _dataContext.GetChangeSet();
            _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error saving data.  Please contact support",
                "Survey Error.", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
}
```

Unfortunately after updating result.StillNeeded in the foreach the dbResult is still showing the old value.  I've seen very similar code on MSDN as well as Stack Overflow which appears to work fine.

Any thoughts on why this might be occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure but where is the definition of dataContext ?

Comment: _dataContext is a private variable initialized in the constructor of the WPF form, as simply _dataContext = new DFSDataContext();.

Comment: If you can, you should migrate to Entity Framework, it's much better than Linq to Sql

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  My (awesome) DBA created an ID column with autoincrement and didn't set it as the primary key.  After doing this, then setting a primary key in the DBML designer, then finally setting "AutoSync" to "OnInsert" I was able to correctly update the database.